# I can't seem to get my addition function to add the two numbers together

Tags: javascript, html, math, addition

here's the code

`how do you get my code to add the two numbers in the addition function?
I've tried different things within the addition function but nothing seems to stop it from adding it together like a string.
I don't know what else to add , so this for being able to post the question. and i also have a currency converter question, idk if you can dm but lmk if you're available, thank you.

how do you get my code to add the two numbers in the addition function?
I've tried different things within the addition function but nothing seems to stop it from adding it together like a string.
I don't know what else to add , so this for being able to post the question. and i also have a currency converter question, idk if you can dm but lmk if you're available, thank you.

how do you get my code to add the two numbers in the addition function?
I've tried different things within the addition function but nothing seems to stop it from adding it together like a string.
I don't know what else to add , so this for being able to post the question. and i also have a currency converter question, idk if you can dm but lmk if you're available, thank you.`

```
enter code here
```

```
`html`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Basic math </title>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin: 30px;}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<form>
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br>
2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>
<input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Multiply" />
<input type="button" onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
<input type="button" onclick="addition()" value="add" />
<input type="button" onclick="minus()" value="minus"/>
<input type="button" onclick="modeBy()" value="mode"/>
</form>
<p>The Result is : <br>
<span id = "result"></span>
</p>
</body>
<script src="sum.js"></script>
</html>
```

java:

```
function multiplyBy()
{
        num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}

function divideBy() 
{ 
        num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
}



//I can't seem to get my addition to actually add the numbers together.//
function addition() {
       
  const num1= document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
   const  num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;   
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= parseInt(num1 + num2);
   
}

function minus()
{
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
        
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 - num2;
}

function modeBy()
{
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 % num2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `document.getElementById("firstNumber").value` return `string`

And `+` operator of javascript with `string` : `'1' + '2' = '12'`

With `/, *, %` , value is treated as a number

You should convert to number for calculator with `Number()` or `parseInt()` : same as :

```js
function multiplyBy()
{
  let num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  let num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}

function divideBy() 
{ 
  let num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  let num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
}



//I can't seem to get my addition to actually add the numbers together.//
function addition() {
  let num1= document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  let num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= Number(num1) + Number(num2);
  // or
  //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
}

function minus()
{
  let num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  let num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 - num2;
}

function modeBy()
{
  let num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  let num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 % num2;
}
```

```html
<form>
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br>
2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>
<input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Multiply" />
<input type="button" onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
<input type="button" onclick="addition()" value="add" />
<input type="button" onclick="minus()" value="minus"/>
<input type="button" onclick="modeBy()" value="mode"/>
</form>
<p>The Result is : <br>
<span id = "result"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , unfortunately still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing your variables before they get retrieved by the dom is a way to do it.

```
function addition() {
       
  const num1= parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
   const  num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber").value);   
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= num1 + num2;
   
}
```

Comment: still not working unfortunately

Comment: Can you give more details about the problem?

Comment: i needed to create a basic math webpage that that does 'basic math' and i couldn't get the addition function to work even after trying the two solutions posted by using parseInt() and number() to get them to add as numbers and not a string

Comment: Could you make a snippet of your code so we can interact with it better in your post? Or provide a https://playcode.io/javascript link on how you write your code. It would be better to see how you initialize and call things since the two solutions provided should be able to fix it.